# How do I vertically center an NSTextView in a SwiftUI view with NSViewRepresentable?

Tags: macos, swiftui, nstextview

I've got a simple `NSViewRepresentable` that wraps an `NSTextView`.

```swift
struct TextView: NSViewRepresentable {
  typealias NSViewType = NSTextView

  var text: NSAttributedString

  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
    let view = NSTextView()
    // set background color to show view bounds
    view.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBlue
    view.drawsBackground = true
    view.isEditable = false
    view.isSelectable = false
    return view
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
    nsView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(text)
  }
}
```

I want to center it vertically, so I'm using a `VStack` with `Spacers` above and below.
I want to leave left and right margins around it proportional to the window size, so I've wrapped it in a `GeometryReader` and `frame()`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  func textView() -> some View {
    let text = """
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod \
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      """

    // Note: real application has more complex text than this, *not* using
    // NSAttributedString isn't really an option, at least till SwiftUI has
    // proper rich text support.

    let size: CGFloat = 18
    let font = NSFont(name: "LeagueSpartan-Bold", size: size) 
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
      string: text,
      attributes: [ .foregroundColor: NSColor.systemYellow,
                    .font: font ?? NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: size) ])
    return TextView(text: attrString)
  }

  var body: some View {
    let textView: some View = self.textView()
    return ZStack {
      // use ZStack to provide window background color
      Color(NSColor.systemTeal)
      VStack {
        Spacer()
        GeometryReader { m2 in
          textView.frame(width: m2.size.width / 1.618)
        }
        Spacer()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The horizontal frame works fine, but the vertical spacing isn't working at all:

[image: initial state]

(initial state)

And resizing the window produces shenanigans:

[image: resize from bottom]

(resize from bottom)

[image: resize from bottom to top, then down again]

(resize from bottom to top, then down again)

Oh, and the Preview is completely bananas:

[image: Preview]

If I replace my custom `TextView` with a `SwiftUI` native `Text`, the layout works fine, which suggests that the problem is in `TextView`. (Note also that the default window size is smaller.)

[image: native Text]

It seems likely that the size of the `NSTextView` isn't getting set properly. If I add `nsView.sizeToFit()` to `updateNSView()`:

```swift
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
        nsView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(text)
        nsView.sizeToFit()
    }
```

this gets me the smaller default window size, and stops the text from bouncing to the bottom of the window when I resize up and down, but the text is still pinned near the top of the window, the preview is still broken, and resizing from the bottom still gets the `NSTextView` temporarily filling most of the height of the window.

Other things I've tried fiddling with: `isVerticallyResizable`, `setContentCompressionResistancePriority`, `autoresizingMask` and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`. None of these seem to make any obvious difference.

It seems like what I want is to update the `NSTextView` size when the containing SwiftUI views resize, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to do that, and I might anyway be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to show `NSAttributedString`, as I understood, then approach based on `NSTextField`, as shown below, is more appropriate, because `NSTextView` does not have default internal layout and requires explicit external frame.

[image: demo]

Here is modified representable, `ContentView` does not require changes.

```
struct TextView: NSViewRepresentable {
  typealias NSViewType = NSTextField

  var text: NSAttributedString

  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextField {
    let view = NSTextField()
    // set background color to show view bounds
    view.backgroundColor = NSColor.systemBlue
    view.drawsBackground = true
    view.isEditable = false
    view.isSelectable = false
    view.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    view.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    return view
  }

  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextField, context: Context) {
    nsView.attributedStringValue = text
  }
}
```

Comment: That works. Weirdly, it still wasn't centering for me, but adding an `HStack` inside the `GeometryReader` in `ContentView` fixed that.

Comment: To get the look I wanted, I also had to set `view.isBezeled = false`.